# How to update multiple rows in a php loop which throws a time out 504

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to migrate customers to a new database structure.

I have written a PHP script which loops through every record and determines if that customer has duplicates in the database or not. If there are multiple occurrences, I update all other tables linked to that customer, and update their linked customerID to the latest version of that customer.

The issue I am facing is that running this script by loading migrate.php in a browser takes so long that I get a timeout 504 when running it, even if I run the query for customers names starting with 'A'. Then change to 'B' and run the script, then 'C' and run the script etc... (which would take forever to do anyways).

So my question is: How can I run around 120,000 UPDATE queries either within the PHP loops in the migrate.php page and avoid a 504 timeout (currently set to limit of 5min), or by printing the Queries out, and running them through PHPMyAdmin?

I have printed out (snippet):

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE renewal_reminder SET renewalid='49884' WHERE renewalid='43239';
UPDATE renewal_note SET renewalid='49884' WHERE renewalid='43239';
UPDATE renewal_request SET renewalid='49884' WHERE renewalid='43239';
UPDATE renewal_timeline SET renewalid='49884' WHERE renewalid='43239';
COMMIT;
```

But this still kills PHPMyAdmin and returns an error.

Can this large list of UPDATES be used within PHPMyAdmin to run the script, maybe in batches?

Comment: maybe you can add a column ```IsMigrated TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0```, then after commit, update that column to 1. Repeat until all record has IsMigrated column = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Well...

I ended up **indexing** the customerID in each table that references it, and I ran my original script with the UPDATE queries and it did it in about 5 seconds...

Without the need to INSERT, then copy over the data.

So for anyone with the same problem, try indexing certain columns in your table so your script can reference them quickly.